# Unresolved attribute 'data' for subclass of UserString

Tags: python-3.x, types

I'm using Python 3.7 and PyCharm 2019.1.3, I've made a subclass of [UserString](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) and althought the documentation clearly states I should be able to access the underlying string with `myinstance.data` PyCharm shows me an `Unresolved attribute reference 'data' for class 'Token'`.

Here's my subclass:

```py
from collections import UserString

class Token(UserString):
    def __init__(self, value, is_emoji: bool):
        # if it's not an emoji and a title we lower-case the value
        UserString.__init__(self, value.lower() if not is_emoji and value.istitle() else value)
        self.is_emoji: bool = is_emoji


if __name__ == '__main__':
    token = Token("Sauce", False)
    print(token.data)
```

is it a PyCharm bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @wim, just edited in a minimal exemple, in my main data is highlighted in yellow with the warning I talked about

Comment: token.data is trying to access the data attribute of the token class.. You have not defined anything as 'data' in the token class.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim yes but Token inherits from UserString which should have a public data attribute so in my understanding I'm not supposed to get this warning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can correctly `print(token.data)` in your example, this indeed must be a bug in PyCharm.

You can try to sidestep it by using `super` which likely would trigger a different code analysis path and discover the `.data` member. Did not try it, though.

Comment: thanks for confirming it was not from me (it was my first time using UserString so I wasn't sure), I'm going to file this as a bug then